# my ".modal('show');" does not get my modal to appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to display a modal of a page only when a registration button of a different file is submitted. for ease ill call them page1 and page2.

page1:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register'] == 'REGISTER') {
  ?>
  <script>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  </script>
 <?php
  }
?>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Welcome, New White Card Holder!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h3>Congratulations! you are entitled for a 30-day free trial of our <img src="../img/ribbon-elite.png" class="small-icon"> Elite Membership.</h3>
      <h3>You may begin browsing our cards right away as soon as you close this window</h3>
      <h3>Also, if you wish to avail of our other membership options, <a href="membership.php">click here.</a></h3>
      <h3>Enjoy a wealth of deals for wellness!</h3>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

page2:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER">
```

to put it simply:

- registration is in page2
- modal is in page1
- page2 redirects to page1 after registration is successful
- i want the modal to appear in page1 right after registration is successful in page2

my if condition "if(isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register'] == 'REGISTER')" works when saving the filled up forms to my database, so i assumed that it will do the same with my ".modal('show');" but there is no effect or appearance of the popup when i register successfully. what is wrong with my show modal code?

Comment: redirect after means you no longer have post vars - put something in a session and look for that

Comment: can you elaborate with code?

Comment: You are not posting directly to the page with the modal so there is no post variable so isset($_post) will fail have a google for how to store variables in sessions or pass something along in the querystring and use the get vars